# Rails find all items belongs_to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following three models:

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :order_movies
end
```

models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_movies
  has_many :user, through: :order_movies
end
```

models/order_movies.rb

```
class OrderMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Now I want to return all the movies which were ordered from one specific user.

I tried the following:

```
   def myMovies
     @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
     @movies = OrderMovie.where(:user_id => @user.id).movie

   end
```

But I got this error:

```
undefined method `movie' for #<OrderMovie::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000007c38fc8>
```

What is my failure in this case?

Thanks at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry.

I found a solution working for me:

```
@moviesOrders = OrderMovie.where(:user_id => @user.id)
@movies = Movie.where(id: @moviesOrders.pluck(:movie_id))
```

But is there a smarter way? probably to do this in one line?

Comment: you are writing unnecessary code.  ActiveRecord associations take care of this.  See my solution above.

Comment: Not only writing but doing unnecessary queries to the DB. Instead of a single query, you are doing two.

Answer (score 2):

The `User` object has a relationship for `movies` which is through `order_movies` therefore, if you want all of the `movies` for a specific user look no further than `@user.movies`.

Please read more about ActiveRecord relationships and many-to-many relationships.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you already told Rails that `User has_many: movies ...`:

```
 @user.movies
```